# Telegram Mini App Angular Back and Main buttons

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, telegram, telegram-bot

I am developing a Telegram mini-app using Angular 17 and the Telegram API. I have an issue where the back and home buttons are working unexpectedly. I have home component which has 3 buttons for navigating to different component A, B and C. A and B I show both back and main buttons while in C only back button is shown. On Home the Back and Main buttons are hidden.

I have a bug where when the home component is loaded, the main button for component A is briefly shown and then hidden. And when I go to component A, B or C and then click the back button, I am redirected to Home where the back button sticks to the Home button which is supposed to be hidden.

Another bug is that when I select A from Home for the first time, all the Back and Main buttons load correctly. But when I select  A for the second time, the main and back buttons do not load. This also happened when selecting B and C for the second time.

```
interface TgButton {
  show(): void;
  hide(): void;
  setText(text:string): void;
  onClick(fn: Function): void;
  offClick(fn: Function): void;
  enable() : void;
  disable() : void
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class TelegramService {

  private mainButtonClickHandler?: Function;
  private backButtonClickHandler?: Function;

  private window: Window;
  tg: any;

  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document) {
    this.window = this._document.defaultView!;
    this.tg = this.window.Telegram.WebApp;
  }

  get MainButton(): TgButton {
    return this.tg.MainButton;
  }

  get BackButton(): TgButton {
    return this.tg.BackButton;
  }

  setupMainButton(text: string, callback: () => void): void {
    this.clearMainButton(); 
    this.mainButtonClickHandler = callback;
    this.MainButton.setText(text);
    this.MainButton.onClick(callback);
    this.MainButton.show();
  }

  setupBackButton(callback: () => void): void {
    this.clearBackButton();
    this.backButtonClickHandler = callback;
    this.BackButton.onClick(callback);
    this.BackButton.show();
  }

  clearMainButton(): void {
    if (this.mainButtonClickHandler) {
      this.MainButton.offClick(this.mainButtonClickHandler);
      this.mainButtonClickHandler = undefined;
    }
    this.MainButton.hide();
  }

  clearBackButton(): void {
    if (this.backButtonClickHandler) {
      this.BackButton.offClick(this.backButtonClickHandler);
      this.backButtonClickHandler = undefined;
    }
    this.BackButton.hide();
  }

  sendData(data: object): void {
    this.tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
  }

  ready(): void {
    this.tg.ready();
  }
  
}
```

Home Component

```
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public telegram: TelegramService,private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.configureTelegramButtons();
  }

  private configureTelegramButtons() {
    // Explicitly hide the MainButton when the search component is loaded
    this.telegram.clearMainButton(); 
    this.telegram.clearBackButton();
    this.telegram.ready();
  }

  goToA(){
    this.router.navigate(['/toA'], { });
  }

  goToB(){
    this.router.navigate(['/toB'], { });
  }

  goToC() {
    this.router.navigate(['/myTrips'], { });
  }
}
```

Home View

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="goToA()" >A</button>
      <span>Trip</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="goToB()">B</button>
      <span>Vehicle</span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button (click)="goToC()">C</button>
      <span>Trips</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Component A

```
export class AComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private telegram: TelegramService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setupTelegramButtons();
    this.fetchVehicleDetails();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.telegram.clearBackButton();
    this.telegram.clearMainButton();
  }

  private setupTelegramButtons(): void {
    // Setup MainButton with text and callback for adding a trip
    this.telegram.setupMainButton("Add", () => this.add());

    // Setup BackButton with callback for navigation
    this.telegram.setupBackButton(() => this.goBack());
    
    this.telegram.ready();
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

  async add(): Promise<void> { }
}
```

Component B

```
export class BComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private telegram: TelegramService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setupTelegramButtons();
    this.fetchVehicleDetails();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.telegram.clearBackButton();
    this.telegram.clearMainButton();
  }

  private setupTelegramButtons(): void {
    // Setup MainButton with text and callback for adding a trip
    this.telegram.setupMainButton("Minus", () => this.minus());

    // Setup BackButton with callback for navigation
    this.telegram.setupBackButton(() => this.goBack());
    
    this.telegram.ready();
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

  async minus(): Promise<void> { }
}
```

Component C

```
export class CComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private telegram: TelegramService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTrips();
    this.setupBackButton();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.telegram.clearBackButton();
  }

  private setupBackButton(): void {
    this.telegram.setupBackButton(() => this.goBack());
    this.telegram.ready();
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

}
```